# MySQL: где корневой каталог при указании пути к файлу?

Tags: mysql

Слышал, что в БД не рекомендуется хранить картинки, а лучше хранить путь к файлу. Вот только вопрос: а как правильно указать путь? Что БД считает корневым каталогом, относительно которого надо указать путь?

На данный момент я использую OpenServer; сами базы данных, хранятся, **наверное** в `userdata`. Картинки храню в `img` доменной папки.

Comment: БД фиолетово как вы храните в ней пути. для нее это просто строка, она даже не задумывается, что это может быть некий путь. С файлами БД сама не работает.

Comment: Понятно, т. е. путь следует выбирать относительно файла, где скрипт был запущен, да?

Comment: Это уже зависит полностью от логики вашего приложения. лично я предпочитаю всегда в настройках хранить и полный путь на диске, если надо самому и внешним программам обращаться и путь для ссылок на странице, если они предусмотрены. А в БД хранить вообще как можно меньше. например только имя файла или небольшую часть пути. незачем в БД хранить длинные повторяющиеся строки

Comment: Я не сказал в вопросе, что сайт делаю, не приложение...

Comment: А что же тогда. Сама же БД работать с файлами в принципе не умеет. Так что хранение в ней неких путей без приложения которое потом этими путями воспользуется абсолютно бесполезно

Comment: Ну вообщем попытаюсь ответить сам на свой вопрос (на примере картинки): в БД нужно хранить такой путь к картинке , который будет понят HTML- или PHP- файлом, где есть разметка этой картинки.